# Share Outlook Tasks on 2 computers without Exchange Server

Tags: microsoft-outlook, sync, gtd, tasks

I use Outlook to manage my tasks. The tasks are stored locally in a .pst file. I would like to be able to sync my tasks across my two computers but I don't have access to an Exchange server.

Is there anyway I can sync the tasks between the two computers? I don't need mail, calendar or notes features.

I'm using Outlook 2010 on Windows 7 on both PCs.

Answer (score 1):

If you are simply seeking to sync the .pst files then I would recomend something like Dropbox if you're ok with using a third party service.  If you want to use your own solution you could map a network drive on windows, or use rsync on linux.

Whether or not this will cause problems (being updated while outlook is open, etc.) I don't know.  It's worth a try though.

Comment: Using a Dropbox may cause you problems if you open the pst from another computer before the synch is complete. se here: http://www.lifehacker.com.au/2011/05/how-to-sync-your-desktop-email-client-across-multiple-computers/ down where it says: There are a few caveats to this approach...

Comment: Horrible things will happen if you mess around with PST files. They are quite fragile. I'd agree that they should move around OK with Dropbox, but you will have to make sure Dropbox is done before trying to use the file. I'd suggest trying to use some other system to do this.

Comment: What a...?? Synchronizing PSTs using Dropbox??? Completely insane idea. Don't even ever try to do something like this!

Comment: PSTs should always be on the local drive.  Network based PST are known to have issues